# Trying to toggle or add/remove a class on a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry, had to edit this, it did not paste correctly.

I'm able to remove the Main_Button class, but I am not able to add a class to style it.  Hover works fine, but I'm not able to toggle, or have this button display the extra styling when active.

When one button is clicked, I want it to maintain its `.hover` style, which is working.

Here is the HTML for my radio button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("document ready");
  $('#span1').hide();
  $('#span2').hide();
  $('#span3').show();
  $('#span4').hide();  

  $('#package1').click(function(){
 console.log("package1 clicked");
  $('#span1').show();
  $('#span2').hide();
  $('#span3').hide();
  $('#span4').hide();
  $("#package1").toggleClass('selected');
  //  $('#package1').addClass('selected');
  });
   $('#package2').click(function(){
  console.log("package2 clicked");
  $('#span1').hide();
  $('#span2').show();
  $('#span3').hide();
  $('#span4').hide(); 
  });
     $('#package3').click(function(){
    $(".package3toggle").toggleClass("radiocheked");
  console.log("package3 clicked");
  $('#span1').hide();
  $('#span2').hide();
  $('#span3').show();
  $('#span4').hide();
  });
   $('#package4').click(function(){
    $(".package4toggle").toggleClass("radiocheked");
  console.log("package4 clicked");
  $('#span1').hide();
  $('#span2').hide();
  $('#span3').hide();
  $('#span4').show();

  });  

});
```

```css
.Button_Main {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.22);
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 520px;
    display:  -webkit-inline-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #2fc05a;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.Button_Main:hover {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #f6b93b;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.Button_Main.hovered {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #f6b93b;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.Button_Main:focus {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #f6b93b;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}


.radiochecked {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #f6b93b;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.Button_Main.selected {
color: #ffffff !important;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.22);
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 520px;
    display:  -webkit-inline-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 600;
background: #f6b93b;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.selected {
color: #ffffff !important;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.22);
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 520px;
    display:  -webkit-inline-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 600;
background: #f6b93b;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked {
    color: #ffffff !important;
background: #f6b93b;
border-color: #f6b93b !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span class="Button_Main" id="package1" input type="radio" name="layout" value="1"> Package1</span>
    <span class="Button_Main" id="package2" input type="radio" name="layout" value="2"> Package2</span>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but you are missing the close part of ready: `});`

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, you say you want to maintain the ```.hover``` style but you don't have any hover style on your example

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Once you've corrected the `})` issue this seems to work fine..? You say hover works, but there is no hover states?

Comment: I get an error when I run your code...I don't even see the hover

Comment: I had to edit this, should be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as *Calvin Nunes* already said, you're missing the `});` part for the jQuery script - which will probably solve the problem ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("document ready");
  $('#span1').hide();
  $('#span2').hide();
  $('#span3').show();
  $('#span4').hide();

  $('#package1').click(function() {
    console.log("package1 clicked");
    $('#span1').show();
    $('#span2').hide();
    $('#span3').hide();
    $('#span4').hide();
    $("#package1").toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('#package2').click(function() {
    console.log("package2 clicked");
    $('#span1').hide();
    $('#span2').show();
    $('#span3').hide();
    $('#span4').hide();
  });

});
```

If NOT, you should check if jQuery is fired at all. You can do this by checking the console.log or with a simple alert function ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#package1').click(function() {
    alert("PACKAGE1 was clicked!");
  });

  $('#package2').click(function() {
    alert("PACKAGE2 was clicked!");
  });
});
```

If nothing happens, you probably didn't place the jQuery script right. Try placing it **after** the jQuery library.